# TypeScript does not accept video autoplay, why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, video

Got this error:

```
  Property 'autoplay' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<VideoHTMLAttributes<HTMLVideoElement>, HTMLVideoElement>'. Did you mean 'autoPlay'?

  207 |               playsInline
  208 |               controls={props.isControlsVisible == true}
> 209 |               autoplay={props.isAutoPlay == true}
      |               ^
```

Strange, because here docs says it is a valid attribute.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

Answer (score 1):

Change autoplay to autoPlay. This is a JSX convention, where some DOM props do not match the spec.

Here is a GitHub issue that gives a detailed explanation on why it's Camelcase: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16762